# Qual a diferença entre um link simbólico e um hard link?

Tags: linux, sistema-de-arquivos, unix

No contexto Unix, qual é a diferença entre um **link simbólico** (*soft link*) e um **hard link** e quais comandos são utilizados para criá-los?

Comment: Se quiser se aprofundar em como o Linux gerencia o sistema de arquivos, veja esse artigo: https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking/puis/ch05_01.htm#PUIS-CHP-5-SECT-1

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Um **link simbólico** (soft link) se comporta como um "atalho" para outro arquivo ou diretório. Ou seja, ele praticamente só aponta para este outro arquivo.

- Ao deletar o arquivo original, o link simbólico irá falhar.
- Ao deletar o link simbólico, nada irá acontecer com o arquivo
  original.

Para criar um link simbólico, utilize a opção `-s` no comando `ln`:

```
# Cria um link simbólico "b" -> "a"
ln -s a b
```

---

Um **hard link** é um ponteiro para o *inode* de um arquivo ou diretório.

- Ao deletar o arquivo original ou o hard link, o outro ainda existe (porque o inode é mantido).
- Ao modificar qualquer link apontando para um mesmo inode, todos links, incluindo o arquivo original, são modificados.

Para criar um hard link, utilize o comando `ln`:

```
# Cria um hard link "b" -> "a"
ln a b
```

Comment: Hard link precisa estar na mesma partição um do outro? Eu sei que soft link não, mas hard link me gera dúvidas

Answer (score -1):

Eu uso hardlink para um script de backup e o "atalho" não precisa estar no mesmo diretório.
Qualquer alteração no link altera todos os outros links ou pasta de origem para o inode. Isso acontece pois o local onde fica os dados do arquivo não é o mesmo da pasta que vemos e clicamos para abrir e ver os dados.
É como se o hardlink tivesse vida própria.
Algo que faço muito é: cp -al file1 file2. Neste caso file2 é um hardlink de file1.
E posso criar várias cópias hardlink que todas vão funcionar mesmo que eu apague o file1 original.
Pesquise sobre inode que vai entender porque funciona assim.
Linux é incrível.

Comment: Oi. Você falou sobre ` cp -al` que cria um hard link, mas não explicou sobre a diferença entre o link simbólico e um hard link.

Comment: O Soft Link é um atalho que aponta para um arquivo e este arquivo aponta para o inode que é o local real no disco. Já o Hard Link aponta diretamente para o inode do arquivo real no disco. Se tiver vários Hard Link seria como se tivesse várias cópias do arquivo e todos apontam para o inode do arquivo em si. No soft Link se apagar o arquivo que ele aponta, não terá o acesso ao arquivo e o atalho deixará de funcionar. No Hard Link mesmo se apagar o arquivo o Hard Link continuará funcionando pois ele está ligado diretamente ao inode que é o local real no disco. Então, é mais seguro.

Comment: Olá! Ao elaborar melhor sua resposta, você precisa edita-la. Não use o espaço de comentários, edite sua resposta. Saudações.

Comment: Adicione esse seu comentário ao conteúdo da sua resposta.