# Linux - Link Simbolico + Dropbox

Tags: linux, link

Estou fazendo uso do sublime 3 recentemente e gostaria de deixar ele padrão em todos meus computadores.
Para isto pensei em utilizar o dropbox, que sincroniza automaticamente caso haja alguma alteração.

Pensei um utilizar os links simbólicos `ln -s`, contudo lembrei que isto não daria certo, pois o link simbólico nada mais é que um atalho para o conteúdo da pasta, desta forma se eu alterar algum arquivo no local `.config/sublime-text-3` ele nada fará no dropbox, pois ele nem sequer existe lá.

Pesquisando uma pouco encontrei o [`hark link`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68704/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-um-link-simb%C3%B3lico-e-um-hard-link), que parece ser o que desejo, contudo ao testar ocorreu erro `Operation not permitted`, mesmo eu dando `chmod -R 0777` em todo conteúdo do `.config` e no `Dropbox`, o que eu também não quero.

Ainda nesse contexto me questiono se será possível vincular ambos pois eu estaria fazendo um link simbólico de vários computadores para o mesmo local, então como ficaria a estrutura deste arquivo de vinculo?

Alguém saberia como desenvolver este caso?

Comment: Você tentou fazer o oposto? Você deixaria o arquivo real no Dropbox e faria teu link para a posta do programa.

Comment: @PedroWitzel era isso mesmo, se quiser escrever a resposta.

Comment: uma correção: o link simbólico não é um atalho (igual do Windows) e teoricamente deveria funcionar, utilizo links assim em uma aplicação e todos os arquivos são identificados corretamente através do link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O ideal é ter o arquivo que você pretende compartilar salvo no dropbox, por exemplo:

`/home/me/Dropbox/sublime/.config`

Então em cada computador que você pretende usar o sublime você sobrescreve o arquivo original do sublime por um link simbólico ao arquivo no Dropbox.