# link simbólico com a pasta storage laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Atualmente existe o comando PHP artisan storage:link que faz o link simbólico entre public/storage e storage/app/public. Gostaria de saber como fazer esse link no laravel 5.2 visto que nesta versão não há tal comando

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode fazer diretamente por linha de comando.

### Linux:

```
ls -l -s meuprojeto/storage/app meuprojeto/public
```

### Windows

```
mklink /D "meuprojeto/storage/app" "meuprojeto/public"
```

### Referências

- [Qual a diferença entre um link simbólico e um hard link?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/68704/qual-a-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-um-link-simb%c3%b3lico-e-um-hard-link)
- [Criando Links Simbólicos no Windows com Mklink](https://marciocabreira.wordpress.com/2011/08/14/criando-links-simbolicos-no-windows-com-mklink/)
- [Linux: Criando Links](http://www.hardware.com.br/dicas/criando-links.html)

Comment: Era que eu precisava. Valeu cara :)