# Problema com storage

Tags: laravel

Atualmente possuo a seguinte árvore em minha hospedagem na dreamhost

```
[Core do laravel]
- laracore
-- app
-- bootstrap
-- config ...
[Pasta public fora do core]
- exemplo.com.br
--css
--js
```

Após ajustar as configurações rodou normal.
Mas implementando o admin [Voyager](https://laravelvoyager.com/) o upload de imagem dele está com problema. Pelo que pesquisei percebi que é na configuração do storage.

- Como posso solucionar este problema ?
- Em servidores compartilhados qual a melhor estrutura de arquivos ?
- Tentei rodar o php artisan storage:link, mas posso estar falhando em alguma coisa.

Comment: porque tirou `public` do local correto ? vejo grandes problemas fazendo assim, principalmente porque a pasta `public` é responsável em ter o `index.php` que chama a app.

Comment: Para evitar o acesso direto pelo core. O acesso a index eu apenas acertei a rota do bootstrap do laravel e funciona normal, mas a parte do storage que preciso descobrir como acertar

Comment: Quando você diz: `Para evitar o acesso direto pelo core` a aplicação Laravel, já vem configurada para não acessar diretamente o `core`. Agora se você remove a parte do `public` do local dela a parte do `storage` não funciona também. Bom tente configurar o Laravel da mesma forma que você programa, não vai ter nenhum problema e o que você disse não está correto.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic, obrigado por me esclarecer.
Após inúmeras buscas resolvi meu problema com esse link [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239080/link-simb%C3%B3lico-com-a-pasta-storage-laravel-5-2?rq=1)